# Scrollorama Parallax for Responsive Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, parallax

I am working on a website where Im trying to use the js plugin scrollorama - http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/

I've set up the plugin on the site fine, except my divs are done in percentages and resize according to window size, and evidently it doesnt work well with the parallax plugin. The plugin absolute positions the divs and gives defines the 'top' property in pixels. On resize it doesnt change and it causes the divs to be have gaps in between them.

I found on another SO question a possible solution but when trying to alter to work for my site it doesnt seem to do anything. This is the plugin js -- [Pastebin JS](http://pastebin.com/69gtZHkr)

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925174/scrollorama-and-responsive-webdesign/18190847#18190847)

Overall I would like to add a class to the div sections and have the necessary css properties calculated by screen size/percentages.

Also I noticed a error in the console log, it may be effecting things as well -- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pin' of undefined - at line 313

Answer (score 0):

For the last bit, I also had the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pin' of undefined" error - the problem was that on my original scrollorama call I had targetted the blocks I wanted to animated.

To fix it, I added a parent container called #blocks to house all the individual blocks, and then called it thus:

```
var scrollorama = $.scrollorama({
    blocks: '#blocks'
});
```